# Get full call stack of all of the relevant methods in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a `Redux` app and I am using `redux-dev-tools` for its debugging primarily. Unfortunately its often not enough to debug and get clear vision of which methods call which. I am looking for a way to see all of the methods called from the point I change something on the screen to the point where the updates stop. What I want to see is just a set of the ***relevant*** methods called with their lines of codes in the app. `redux-dev-tools` just shows the dispatched actions and then changes in the state (`trace` - is useful but thats very little), but thats not enough for me: I want to know full call stack excluding what is done behind the scenes by the `redux` itself. Are there any tools for that? How would you approach the issue? The ideal case would be the generation of some kind of chart with the call stack and lines of codes.

I can have such a situation when an action is triggered, then asynchronous request runs, then half of the page gets updated and redrawn, then another request happens, etc. I want to know better the call stack in this case. Or imagine if a single button click causes several requests to run and multiple actions to be dispatched, etc. Its for overcomplicated cases. I need to have clear diagrams/methods for better debugging and optimization.

Comment: I think Google dev tools is the best choice in this case

Comment: Unfortunately, this really isn't feasible due to the async behavior of React.  For example, picture `dispatch A -> Redux store update -> component X renders -> useEffect dispatches action B`.  There just isn't a direct line or sequence between all of those.